# Facebook SDK (Require "Like" for access)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I only want people that `like'd` our `Facebook` page to access a specific section of the site. But i'm relatively new with the `Facebook SDK`. Is there a way to check whether someone liked our page? If not possible with `SDK` are there other reliable ways to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Like-gating is not allowed by the Facebook platform policies (chapter 4.5).

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.